# Typescript map files in directory other than generated js (outDir)

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

To avoid cluttering, is there a way to have the map files in some folder other than the outDir in tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions?

I see no option anywhere but perhaps there's some hidden trick.

Comment: are you using angular or just typescript?

Comment: @AntonBks just typescript